# Windows 10 showing me new image each time on reboot before login screen

Tags: login, windows, windows-10

Windows 10 is showing me a new image each time I reboot my PC, before the login screen appears. Once I click this image say - then login screen comes up. How I turn off this feature of showing me new images each time?